# Drag and Drop method works incorrectly on first use

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

I want to place several view objects on the screen where the user drags and drops with the drag and drop method. But this strangely misbehaves on first use and places it not where the user left it, but in a very unrelated place, sometimes even off the screen. However, after the first use, there is no such problem. It puts it exactly where I want it. What is the source of this problem?

**setOnDragListener()**

```
contentTableLayout.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
    Log.i(TAG, " event.getAction(): " + event.getAction() + " getView: ID: " + view.getId() + " getContext: " + view.getContext());
    String getImageFileNameSelectedRoom = getImageFileNameToRoom();

    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
      if (event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
        View draggedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
        initialX = draggedView.getX();
        initialY = draggedView.getY();
        Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_DRAG_STARTED -> initialX: " + initialX + " initialY: " + initialY);
   
        changeBackgroundColorOnDrag(view, "#664CAF50", true);

        return true;

      }
      return event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
      changeBackgroundColorOnDrag(view, "#664CAF50", true);

      return true;

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
      return true;

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

      changeBackgroundColorOnDrag(view, "#66D32121", true);
      return true;

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
      Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_DROP -> ");


      View draggedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
      ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) draggedView.getParent();
      owner.removeView(draggedView);

      FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) view;
      container.addView(draggedView);

      View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(draggedView);
      Point shadowSize = new Point();
      shadowBuilder.onProvideShadowMetrics(shadowSize, new Point());

      int x = (int) event.getX() - draggedView.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
      int y = (int) event.getY() - draggedView.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;


      draggedView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

      Log.i(TAG, "ACTION_DROP -> " + x + "  y: " + y);

      draggedView.setX(x);
      draggedView.setY(y);

      draggedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      return true;

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
      if (!event.getResult()) {

        if (getImageFileNameSelectedRoom != null) {
          File targetFile = findImageFile(getImageFileNameSelectedRoom);

          if (targetFile != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
            ((FrameLayout) view).setBackground(bitmapDrawable);

            view.invalidate();
          } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Resim dosyası bulunamadı.");
          }

        }

        View droppedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
        droppedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
      return true;

    default:
      break;
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

**setOnLongListener()**

```
mainView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) view.getTag());
                    ClipData dragData = new ClipData((CharSequence) view.getTag(), new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}, item);
                    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                    Log.i(TAG, " getXFromView: " + view.getX() + "getYFromView: " + view.getY());


                    view.startDrag(dragData, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

In the above code, the first drag-and-drop operation works incorrectly. When I try the code below, the first drag-and-drop operation is fine, but this time the next ones are broken.

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
    // ...
    int x = (int) (initialX + event.getX() - shadowSize.x / 2);
    int y = (int) (initialY + event.getY() - shadowSize.y / 2);

//initialX and initialY values come from the ACTION_DRAG_STARTED case.
    // ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved with help from another source.

All drag-and-drop functions worked correctly when I **removed** the code below:

```
draggedView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, but code below helped me:

```
val tempWidth = draggableItem.width
val tempHeight = draggableItem.height
draggableItem.layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(tempWidth, tempHeight)
```